# What's wrong in my computation of the sectional curvature of Poincare disk

Tags: calculus, riemannian-geometry, curvature

let $(D,g_0)$ be the standard Poincare disk $$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2<1\}$$ $$g_0(x,y)=\dfrac{4\mathrm{d} x\otimes\mathrm{d} x+4\mathrm{d} y\otimes\mathrm{d} y}{\left(1-(x^2+y^2)\right)^2}$$compute sectional curvature.

let $X=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x},\,Y=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}$，for $$\nabla_{X}X=\dfrac{8}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}\left(xX-yY\right)$$$$\nabla_{Y}X=\nabla_{X}Y=\dfrac{8}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}\left(yX+xY\right)$$$$\nabla_YY=\dfrac{8}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}\left(yY-xX\right)$$$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\dfrac{8x}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}=\dfrac{8(1-x^2-y^2)}{(1-x^2-y^2)^4}+\dfrac{8x(-3)(-2x)}{(1-x^2-y^2)^4}=\dfrac{8(1+5x^2-y^2)}{(1-x^2-y^2)^4}$$
so
\begin{align*}
    &\langle\nabla_X\nabla_YX,Y\rangle  =\left\langle\nabla_X\left(\dfrac{8}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}(yX+xY)\right),Y\right\rangle\\
    = &\,\,\dfrac{8y\langle\nabla_XX,Y\rangle}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}+\dfrac{8(1+5x^2-y^2)}{(1-x^2-y^2)^4}\langle Y,Y\rangle+\dfrac{8x\langle\nabla_XY,Y\rangle}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}
\end{align*} and
\begin{align*}
    &\langle\nabla_Y\nabla_XX,Y\rangle  =\left\langle\nabla_Y\left(\dfrac{8}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}(xX-yY)\right),Y\right\rangle\\
    = &\,\,\dfrac{8x\langle\nabla_YX,Y\rangle}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}-\dfrac{8(1-x^2+5y^2)}{(1-x^2-y^2)^4}\langle Y,Y\rangle-\dfrac{8y\langle\nabla_YY,Y\rangle}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
    &\langle R_{XY}X,Y\rangle  =\langle-\nabla_X\nabla_YX+\nabla_Y\nabla_XX,Y\rangle\\
    =&\,\,-\dfrac{8(2+4x^2+4y^2)}{(1-x^2-y^2)^4}\langle Y,Y\rangle=-\,\dfrac{4^3(1+2x^2+2y^2)}{(1-x^2-y^2)^6}
\end{align*} so the sectional curvature $$K=\dfrac{\langle R_{XY}X,Y\rangle}{|X\wedge Y|^2}=\dfrac{\langle R_{XY}X,Y\rangle}{\langle X,X\rangle\langle Y,Y\rangle}=-\,\dfrac{4(1+2x^2+2y^2)}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}\neq -1\qquad ?????$$ I'm going to cry...

---

now I know where my stupid mistake is. The first formula, the connection, is $$\nabla_{Y}X=\nabla_{X}Y=\dfrac{8}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}\left(y\dfrac{X}{\Vert X\Vert^2}+x\dfrac{Y}{\Vert Y\Vert^2}\right)$$ The other two formulas about connection are the same. Then I can compute the correct result $$K\equiv -1$$ Very grateful to Deane and Andrew D.Hwang for their guidance and encouragement !!!

Comment: You can’t learn differential geometry without tears along the way.

Comment: I suggest redoing the calculation from scratch a few more times (how many times have you already redone the calculation?). Think about each step very carefully And do it very slowly, one small step at a time. No shortcuts. Another option is to learn a different approach. I recommend using a moving frame and differential forms. There might be quicker and easier ways to learn this, vut I don't know any.

Comment: @Deane I've wasted two days ... More than 10 complete inspections

Comment: ::sympathy:: Having a calculation not work out is maddening. A couple of notes: The time you've occupied so far is not wasted, it's helping form and strengthen your neural connections. I second Deane's suggestion to start _from scratch_ and to proceed _in small steps with no shortcuts_, but recommend stepping away for a day or two to clear out whatever assumptions are sending this off the rails. <> FWIW, I can't easily see why the first three equations (the covariant derivatives) are true; not saying they're wrong, but I wouldn't take them for granted without reason.

Comment: Sounds like you’re doing better than I gave you credit for. So now you should do the opposite. Walk away from this and stay away for a few days. Then come back and show us how you got the first few equations. But not now. You need a break.

Comment: !!!!! Thank you both. I know where my stupid mistake is. And I am very grateful for your encouragement!!!

Comment: That's great you found the mistake! If the correct might be of interest to others, it's reasonable to post an answer yourself. In any case, the sense of resolution when details fall into place is on some level why we do mathematics, and the mistake was surely not stupid, at least not in a self-perjorative sense. (I prefer the term _avoidable_.)